# Choose a specific month or week when rendering a Vuetify calendar

Tags: vue.js, calendar, vuetify.js

When the page loads I would like to be able to specify which week or month is being displayed in vuetify for week and month calendars, respectively. So far I Haven't found a way to do this on page load. It appears to show me the month or week that includes today's date no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it appears that you simply need to set the calendar's v-model or value to a simple string, i.e. '01-01-2020'.